# Insert data by TADOCommand in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe5

I have a table with four fields, one of those fields is the primary key.
When I run the following commands:

```
var
  iAffectedRows: integer;
begin
  ADOCommand1.CommandText := 'insert into table_1(Field_1, Field_2, Field_3)   values(:A_Field_1, :A_Field_2, :A_Field_3)';      

  ADOCommand1.Parameters.FindParam('A_Field_1').Value := '100';
  ADOCommand1.Parameters.FindParam('A_Field_2').Value := '200';
  ADOCommand1.Parameters.FindParam('A_Field_3').Value := '300';

  ADOCommand1.Execute(iAffectedRows);
end;
```

The result is :

[image]

The **Field_1** value is 0.

(This result is due to run the command : `ADOCommand1.Execute(iAffectedRows)`)

But with this command everything is correct :`ADOCommand1.Execute()`

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you already have the solution - call the no-argument version of `Execute()`.

```
function Execute: _Recordset;
```

You are calling the 1-argument version of `Execute()`, which does not output the number of rows affected:

```
function Execute(const Parameters: OleVariant): _Recordset;
```

By passing `iAffectedRows` to this version, you are replacing the first parameter value with whatever value `iAffectedRows` initially contains, which just happens to be 0.

If you want to receive the number of rows affected, you need to use the 2-argument version of `Execute()` instead:

```
function Execute(var RecordsAffected: Integer; const Parameters: OleVariant): _Recordset;
```

For example:

```
var
  iAffectedRows: integer;
begin
  ADOCommand1.CommandText := 'insert into table_1(Field_1, Field_2, Field_3) values(:A_Field_1, :A_Field_2, :A_Field_3)';

  ADOCommand1.Parameters.FindParam('A_Field_1').Value := '100';
  ADOCommand1.Parameters.FindParam('A_Field_2').Value := '200';
  ADOCommand1.Parameters.FindParam('A_Field_3').Value := '300';

  ADOCommand1.Execute(iAffectedRows, EmptyParam);
end;
```

Or:

```
var
  iAffectedRows: integer;
begin
  ADOCommand1.CommandText := 'insert into table_1(Field_1, Field_2, Field_3) values(:A_Field_1, :A_Field_2, :A_Field_3)';    
  ADOCommand1.Execute(iAffectedRows, VarArrayOf('100', '200', '300'));
end;
```